# MySQL Get Points from user id

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Note: new to mysql

I am trying to get points from user id ( please view attached table image)

[image]

qa_ is my custom table prefix

I am using wordpress and want to get current logged in user id and want to pass it so can get points of that user id.

Here what I am trying but nothing work

```
function qa_points($userid){
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = 'qa_';
    $points = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT *
        FROM ${prefix}userpoints
        WHERE points = userid
    "); 

    return '(points '.$points['points'].')';

}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `WHERE userid = $userid`?

Comment: ah! just tried but how to pass userid to get points?

Comment: Thanks to whom giving me negative vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the points from a user, you have to select the correct user:

```
$points = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT *
        FROM " . $prefix . "userpoints
        WHERE userid = $userid");
```

Comment: I tried this just before you post but I don't understand how I can pass the userid to get points

Comment: Yes but when I am using get_results its giving me Array not points and when I am trying to use get_var its echoing userid itself like 1 or 5 etc. `<?php echo qa_points($current_user->ID); ?>`

Comment: Query works, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a415b/1   You have to provide more info on futher questions

Comment: I am returning function with this `return '(points '.$points.')';` and passing current user id with `global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();` and `<?php echo qa_points($current_user->ID); ?>` but with get_results its displaying Array while with get_var its displaying userid itself e.g 1 instead of user's points

Answer (score 1):

```
function qa_points($userid){
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = 'qa_';
    $points = $wpdb->get_row("
        SELECT points
        FROM ".$prefix."userpoints
        WHERE userid = $userid
    "); 

    return '(points '.$points->points.')';

}
```

Comment: I tried by passing user id like this `echo qa_points($current_user->ID);` but its not giving output. any idea